# How to Load API Test at run time in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Is it possible to Load API test at run time from GUI Test .

Like we have option to load test with function "LoadAndRunAction".

For API Test we have "RunAPITest" but we have to Load file before executing suite.

So is it possible to load API test also at run time.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no documented way to do this.**

This does not mean it is impossible, just that nobody figured out how, at least: yet.

It's comparable to the situation that we had when `LoadAndRunAction` didn't exist. It was possible to take the static version of this function, `RunAction`, which requires the target action to be present at design-time, and replace (at runtime) its target action with the action that you really want to call.

This of course involves patching the `RunAction` target action's files with the files of the action that you really want to call, and thus is a kind of hack which will make you cry whenever technical details about the internal data formats and locations change from UFT release to UFT release (which is unlikely to happen, though).

As there is no "`LoadAndRun`-style" dynamic `RunAPITest` routine, you could apply the same technique:

At design time:

- Create a `RunAPITest` call to some API test at design-time

At runtime (programmatically, of course):

- Replace that API test files' with the files of the API test that you really want to call (by copying them, probably)
- Execute the `RunAPITest` call.

The whole thing gets more complicated if your artifacts are stored in QC/ALM, and not in the filesystem. You'd need to modify the correct database contents to replace the API test's content, which probably is not a trivial task.

However, your question was: "Is it possible", and -- **yes, it is possible, for example if you apply the receipt used to create a dynamic RunAction routine. There is no documented or ready-to-use solution as of yet, though.**

** Addendum -- Btw, for BPT components, the same dilemma exists. It is not possible, at runtime, to specify the component to execute, nor is it possible to call a component from a component, neither bound "static" nor "dynamic". Since there is no way to store a component in the filesystem, one would really have to "JIT-patch" the database to simulate a dynamic component call.

Answer (score 0):

Public Function ExcelWorkSheetExists(oWorkBook, sSheet)

```
    Dim iCount

    If Not oWorkBook Is Nothing Then
            For  iCount = 1 To oWorkBook.WorkSheets.Count
                   If Trim(UCase(sSheet)) = Trim(UCase(oWorkBook.Worksheets(iCount).Name)) Then
                             ExcelWorkSheetExists = Cint(iCount)
                             Exit Function
                    End If
            Next
            ExcelWorkSheetExists = False
    Else
            ReportEvent "warning", "ExcelWorkSheetExists:oWorkBook Object is not current set", "ExcelWorkSheetExists:oWorkBook Object is not current set", False
            ExcelWorkSheetExists = False    
    End If
```

End Function